# Accessing WAR with www.myApp.com instead of www.myApp.com:8080/myApp, Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, web.xml, tomcat8

i know there are several topics about this, but after days i am not able to localize and solve this problem. the steps i've done so far:

1. installed tomcat 8.5.8
2. changed the following lines in /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml

   ```
   <Host name="www.myApp.com"  appBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps"  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
     <Alias>myApp.com</Alias>     
     <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/myApp" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
   </Host>
   ```
3. deployed  myApp.war under /opt/tomcat/webapps
4. started tomcat
5. check directory /opt/tomcat/webapps and found following content

   ```
   -ROOT
   -docs
   -examples
   -host-manager
   -manager
   -myApp
   myApp.war
   ```
6. check /opt/tomcat/logs and found no error during startup
7. open page www.myApp.com in browser

well, i see the welcome page of myApp, but all resources (.css, .js,...) are not loaded, because /myApp is still present in the src-attribute

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myApp/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/myApp/javax.faces.resource/main.css">
```

instead it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/main.css">
```

is there anything important i'm  missing? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

with regard to the comments the following changes made it work:

1. renamed Tomcats ROOT-Folder to ROOT_TEMP
2. deleted /opt/tomcat/webapps/myApp and /opt/tomcat/webapps/myApp.war
3. uncomment in server.xml

   ```
   <!--Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/myApp" debug="0" reloadable="true"/-->
   ```
4. deploy myApp as "ROOT.war"